# How to Call .NET web API Post service in Android

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

I have one web API service written in .NET.
The service reads token from Header and data with in body.

I am looking Android code that call this server (It should pass token string in header and Json data in body. Please share code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this AsyncTask class :

```
    public class GetEvents extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,String> {



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... TripId) {
        return POSTJson(URLs.API_URL);
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //code after execution 
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    public String POSTJson(String url) {

        UserToken = "YourToken"; 
        String json;
        URL obj;
        try {
            obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con;
            con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            json = DATAtoJSON(TripId).toString();

//Requset headers 
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Token", UserToken);


  // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
//request parameters 
            wr.writeBytes(json);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
 //receive data from request
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JSONObject DATAtoJSON(int TripId) {
        //API corresponding keys
        String TripId_Key = History_Json_Attribute.TripId;
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.accumulate(TripId_Key,TripId);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

this code sends a json object with TripId and "token" header to an API url 
make sure that the json names match the parameter and header name or else there will be an error